# Is it possible to add a watermark when the user takes a screenshot of my Android App pages?

Tags: android

I don't want to block the user to take screenshots, but I'd like to add a watermark to it so where ever he uses it, there will be my mark.

If yes, how how could I do it?

Thanks.

Comment: How is he taking the screenshot? Using the device hardware keys, or is there an option in your app to take a screenshot?

Comment: Device's hardware keys.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible, because taking a screenshot using the device hardware keys, you've no control over it. You can at most listen to the screenshot event, but there's no way you can add a watermark to it.

Comment: But I've seen apps that prevent the screenshot. Which means they can listen to the event before it happens. So it means I can prevent but I can't do anything else before the event executes, right?

Comment: Can you give an example of an app that prevents taking screenshot? You can listen to the screenshot event, but you cannot prevent it.

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to remember one but I can't. But I've seen.

Comment: @Antrromet take a look at any mobile banking app

Comment: @K20GH Can you send the link?

Comment: The Wells Fargo app does not allow screen shots to be taken while looking at your account.

Answer (score 0):

With ContentObserver, you can do that like below.

[watermark screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofWVX.jpg)

you can modify watermark whatever you want (using bitmap)

checkout this [Android Screenshot Service](https://github.com/SinsangMarket/ASS) git project